# React Navigation Property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need help because I have problem with react navigation to redirect,
I try the walkthroughs of others post who not work with my code

in my app I have this navbar with image

**NavBar**
[image]

`onclick` at this image I have this error 
**App error**

[image]

Into my NavBar.js code:

```
  <TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() =>
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat')}
  >
  <Image
    source={require('../../img/Contact.png')}
    style={styles.helpStyle}
  />
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

My Router.js

```
export const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeList,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: <NavBar />,
      },
    },
  HairList: {
    screen: HairList
  },
  Message: {
    screen: Chat
  }
});

export const CalendarStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeList
  },
  HairList: {
    screen: HairList
  },
  BookingList: {
    screen: BookingList
  },
});

export const FavorisStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeList
  },
  HairList: {
    screen: HairList
  },
});

export const ProfilStack = StackNavigator({
  Profil: {
    screen: Profil
  },
});

export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: (
            <Image
              style={{ width: 36, height: 32 }}
              source={require('./img/home.png')}
            />
      ),
    },
  },
  Calendar: {
    screen: CalendarStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: (
            <Image
              style={{ width: 36, height: 37 }}
              source={require('./img/planning.png')}
            />
      ),
    },
  },
  Favoris: {
    screen: FavorisStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: (
            <Image
              style={{ width: 36, height: 32 }}
              source={require('./img/favoris.png')}
            />
      ),
    },
  },
  Profil: {
    screen: ProfilStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: (
            <Image
              style={{ width: 38, height: 32 }}
              source={require('./img/Logo.png')}
            />
      ),
    },
  },
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: false,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#ed6e74',
    },
  },
});

export const Router = StackNavigator({
  Tabs: {
    screen: Tabs,
  },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
});
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router />
    );
  }
}
```

I need to redirect to the chat screen after click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I send `navigation` to the with `NavBar`.

In Router.js:

```
navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  header: <NavBar navigation={navigation} />,
  },
}
```

Then in NavBar.js:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Chat')}>
    <Image
        source={require('../../img/Contact.png')}
        style={styles.helpStyle}
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

to redirect with header button import this

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
```

and add withNavigation

```
export default withNavigation(NavBar);
```